# Explorador de Soluciones Visual Studio 2019, no funciona?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual

Se que esta pregunta puede ser una troleada pero no me funciona y ya me rendi .

Cada que creo un nuevo proyecto en una solucion, este no los muestra (1ra Imagen) y nose porque, solo cuando le doy a la opcion de la izquierda (Cambiar entre soluciones y vistas disponibles) los muestra pero en carpetas (2da Imagen).

Alguna manera de volverlo a como deberia ser?

La ultima imagen es de un proyecto que tenia, al abrirlo si lo muestra como deberia ser.

[image: aaaaa]

[image: NOOOOOOOOO]

[image: Siiiiiiiiii]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: @gbianchi, sabes por qué el bot de Comunidad está haciendo los comentarios en inglés?

Comment: @Arriel estamos en proceso de traducir los comentarios... esta explicado en meta